# sorting a factor variable based on a numeric variable

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I am trying to sort a factor variable **Category** , the **Amount** column is numeric, and
**Units** is a factor where (B=Billions, M=Millions, K=Thousands)

```
d <- read.table(text="Category        Amount    Units
A  1.2   B
B  2.4   K
C  3.2   M
A  2.3   B
B  4.5   M
C  6.5   K", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

**Here is what I have done**
`d$Total <- ifelse(d$Units=="B", 1000000000, ifelse(d$Units =="M", 1000000, ifelse(d$Units == "K", 1000, 0)))`

`d$Total <- d$Total * Amount`

`arrange(d, desc(Amount), Units)`

**My Question, Is there a better way of acheiving it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
options(scipen=999)
v1 <- as.character(d$Units)
d$Total <- setNames(c(1e9, 1e3, 1e6),unique(v1))[v1]*d$Amount
```

---

If we need it in `dplyr` way

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
  mutate(Units = as.character(Units),
         Total = setNames(c(1e9, 1e3, 1e6),
              unique(Units))[Units]*Amount) %>%
  arrange(Units, desc(Amount)) 
#   Category Amount Units      Total
# 1        A    2.3     B 2300000000
# 2        A    1.2     B 1200000000
# 3        C    6.5     K       6500
# 4        B    2.4     K       2400
# 5        B    4.5     M    4500000
# 6        C    3.2     M    3200000
```

---

Another option is using `gsubfn` to replace the values

```
library(gsubfn)
d$Total <- as.numeric(gsubfn(".", list(B= 1e9, M=1e6, 
       K=1e3), as.character(d$Units))) * d$Amount
```

and then `arrange` the dataset as earlier.